# Surveys: How to remove all entries?

Tags: survey-list

We have created a survey and have been testing it by adding responses. Now we want to open it up to the 'public'. Note that my user has Full Access to the survey.

**How can I remove all of the test responses?**

I have deleted all the responses which are listed and I can see no more. However, in the overview, it says there are 27 items in the list but when I select 'show all responses' it says that there are no responses.

** What does *that* mean?**

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. What I have found is as follows:

When a response is started it is added to the total number of responses. It remains 'checked out' to that user until the response is completed. Only then will it be visible to the survey owners. That explains the discrepancy between the number of items in the list and the number of items shown in 'show all responses'.

Incomplete responses can only be removed by the users who own them.

I found the following quote:

*'If you created the survey on a publishing site, it will not show the
incomplete responses.  The only time I was able to view incomplete responses
was if the survey was created on a collaboration/team site.'*

Hope this helps. M$ could have made the overview a little bit more informative, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but I don't agree with any of the solutions offered here.

The numbering does not reset to zero when responses are deleted, it is part of the audit trail settings of SharePoint.  Nor do they stay checked out.  Responses don't check out at all, they get listed as not complete.

It was either from people deleting responses they did not want to see, or from testing branching logic then deleting responses.

The only way to set the count back to zero, is to save the survey as a template - without including the content - then recreate it based that template.

Answer (score 2):

This should not be the case. If you have deleted the responses then they should be reset to 0. How ever There are two possibilities

1. There are partially completed surveys which will not be visible to you. I am aware that you have not made it public but you mentioned "we" in your question so i assume there must be someone else who have not completed the survey.
2. Did you refresh the page? ;-)

Comment: Yes. I think they are incomplete responses. I just don't know who didn't complete the questions...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue...test responses causing response count to be 2, even though all responses were deleted.  Resolved by following the suggestion to save the survey as a template, delete the old survey, then create a new survey using the template.  Fixed in 2 minutes!  Even was able to keep the old link by ensuring I deleted the old survey first, and created the new survey from the template with the same name as the first.