# How do you get the response counter back to zero in a SharePoint 2007 Survey

Tags: 2007, survey-list, survey

In a survey created in SP2007 the results counter says there are 8 responses. However,
after going to the view all responses page and deleting everything I see the page say "there Are no responses." But on the survey page it still says" that there are 8.  Do you how I might return the counter to 0?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this entry : 
[Surveys: How to remove all entries?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1947/surveys-how-to-remove-all-entries)

Short answer is that you will have to save your survey as a template without the content and then recreate it.

The explanation is that you have incomplete responses in your survey, meaning that they are "checked out" the respondent and you cannot view/remove them (even Site Collection Admin). Users can save their response when you use Page Separators. I've never found a way other than to recreate the survey.